# Interfacing C++ with Python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ctypes, swig, boost-python

I have a c++ (C++ 17) [library](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-cpp) and a function dependent on this library. I want to call this function from python(python 3). How can it be done?

I have read some tutorials using swig and ctypes but I don't know how can I make it work for an external shared library.

**Details:**
I have this **libclickhouse-cpp-lib.so** .so file and the header files for this library in **/path/to/header/files** directory.

```
/*File cpp_reader.h*/
#pragma once
int reader();
```

```
/* File cpp_reader.cpp*/
#include <clickhouse/client.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "cpp_reader.h"
using namespace clickhouse;
int reader()
{
    Client client(ClientOptions().SetHost("localhost"));
    int numrows=0;
    client.Select("SELECT count(*) from test.test_table",
        [&numrows] (const Block& block)
        {
            for (size_t i=0;i<block.GetRowCount();++i)
            {
                numrows+=block[0]->As<ColumnUInt64>()->At(i);
            }
        }
    );
    return(numrows);
}
```

I want to call this read function from python. I have gone through some posts using swig and ctypes but haven't been able to figure out. If it can be done easily using anything else, please suggest that too.

*Additional Information:*
This is how I run the code in c++

```
/*File: main.cpp*/
#include <clickhouse/client.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
using namespace clickhouse;
int main()
{
    /// Initialize client connection.
    Client client(ClientOptions().SetHost("localhost"));
    int numrows=0;
    client.Select("SELECT count(*) from test.test_table",
        [&numrows] (const Block& block)
        {
            for (size_t i=0;i<block.GetRowCount();++i)
            {
                numrows+=block[0]->As<ColumnUInt64>()->At(i);
            }
        }
    );
    std::cout<<"Number of Rows: "<<numrows<<"\n";
}
```

Compilation:
**g++ -std=c++1z main.cpp -I/path/to/header/files -I/usr/include/python3.6m/ -L. /path/to/libclickhouse-cpp-lib.so -o outfile**

**LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/so_file/directory**
**export LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

*/path/to/so_file/directory contains libclickhouse-cpp-lib.so*

**./outfile**

Comment: [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) is the easiest way in my experience.  [boost.python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) is also decent if you are already using Boost.  I wouldn't recommend `ctypes` unless you are just hacking around with hobby projects, and I wouldn't recommend `swig` unless you need to expose your C++ to a bunch of other languages in addition to Python.

Comment: I see no reason for `cpp_reader.h` to `#include <clickhouse/client.h>` or even `iostream`. I suggest you remove them to lessen the confusion on any binding generator

Comment: Did you try https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+write+a+python+library+in+c%2B%2B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it may be best to keep it simple and not use binding generators, because all you have here is a simple function that doesn't receive any parameters and simply returns an int.

Your goal can be achieved as follows:

In `cpp_reader.cpp`, prepend the following line before the reader definition:

```
extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
int reader()
{
    ....
```

Now from Python you can simply do:

```
from ctypes import cdll
import os
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath("libclickhouse-cpp-lib.so"))
num_rows = lib.reader()
```

Also don't forget to add `-shared` to the `g++` commandline when compiling the shared object